# Green mould/mushrooms on houseplant soil

Tags: identification, houseplants, soil, pests, fungus

I recently took some cuttings from a friend, let them root in water, and then planted them.

About a week later, suddenly there’s lot of green fungus/mould on the top of the soil!

Any help identifying would be appreciated. Is it harmful to the plant? Will leaving the plant in the sun help? Should I water less...?

I live in a temperate but dry area, and water about 2-3 times a week normally. We’re in Autumn so it’s getting cloudier.

enter image description here[image]

Comment: Looks like a "jelly" type mushroom ; there are several types, I did not find this type with a quick look.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt anyway =)

Answer (score 1):

Autumn is a classic time for most mushrooms/toadstools to appear - these are one of the cup fungi, one of the Pezizaceae https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pezizaceae, possibly Tarzetta  cupularis, though I can't see enough detail to be sure  https://www.first-nature.com/fungi/tarzetta-cupularis.php. If you google 'cup fungi'
and select images, you'll see just how many there are... colour variations of the cups are common.

If your pot does not have drainage holes, find one that does or put some holes in the one you have. This fungi is saprobic, so part of nature's disposal system - it means it lives on decaying material in the soil such as  wood fragments. It will not harm whatever plant you have in the pot, but don't eat them, they are toxic if consumed. The cups will disappear on their own, but the mycelium will remain active on the decaying material, and will produce more fruiting bodies (the cups) next year - ensuring good drainage and not keeping the pot soaking wet will reduce their ability to produce the cups. If you don't like the look of them, you can just pull them off the soil wearing gloves and dispose of them - that will also stop them producing their spores.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the reply! I was mainly just concerned if they will harm the plant or not — good to know they are harmless. Any idea what they are called?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: After finding more photos on the net ,that are better than my book photos , I think you have  a very good ID.